# How to figure out whether a package is already installed?

Tags: package-management, gcc

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 as a guest on a windows host.
Before installing GCC, I need to make sure that the following packages are installed:

GMP, MPFR and MPC

I checked the Ubuntu package site and I think they correspond to:

libgmp10, libmpfr4 and libmpc3

How do I find out whether the packages have already been installed?
If they haven't been installed, how do I install them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to find whether a package is installed or not in Ubuntu. For example if we want to find whether `vim` is installed or not in Ubuntu we can use any of the following commands:

```
dpkg -s vim
dpkg --get-selections | grep 'vim' #I always prefer this one as it shows other packages that has the pattern `vim` in their names, very useful in some cases
dpkg -l vim
apt-cache policy vim
```

Now if want to install a package after finding that its not installed already, just do the following (here we are installing `vim`, just replace vim with whatever package you want):

```
sudo apt-get update #It will update the local cache of repositories, not mandatory but recommended
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Here is a simple `bash` script to check if a package is installed or not, if not then it will install the package. It will ask you to input the name of the package.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What's the name of the package you want to check?"
read package
check=$(dpkg -s $package 2>/dev/null | sed -n '2,3p' | grep -o 'installed')

if [[ "$check" == 'installed' ]]
        then
                echo -e "$package is already Installed\n\n"
else
        echo -e "$package is Not installed\n\n"
        sudo apt-get install $package
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You can list all installed packages via dpkg like this

```
dpkg -l
```

You can then pipe that through grep to only find the things you are interesting in:

```
dpkg -l | grep libgmp10
```

Or you can be less specific in your grep

```
dpkg -l | grep libgmp
```

Grep will find any line in the output with that string.

Installing is easy also

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

Not sure of the package name? Tab complete works in the apt-get install command also, or you can use:

```
sudo apt-cache search <string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo apt-get install $package-name1 $package-name2 $package-name3`, as many packages as you want. If they are already installed, it will say `$package-name is already the newest version.`

Comment: that is not really a good way of seeing if something is installed. Use dpkg instead.

Comment: This is a "kill two birds with one stone" solution. It installs if it isn't already installed, and it tells you if it is installed if it is.

Comment: yes but it doesn't teach OP how to do things properly. OP has 2 distinct questions, how do i see if something is installed? and how do i install things?. apt-get install is not a good way of seeing if things are installed

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood the question. I thought he was asking to check if a package is installed, then install it if it isn't.

Comment: Actually, i think maybe i am just over thinking this. As a "install this if not installed" then yep, apt-get install is fine. For just checking if something is installed then dpkg. Pretty sure i way over-analysed what OP was asking!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can install **GMP** with</strike>

```
 sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

**MPFR**

```
 sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
```

**MPC**

```
 sudo apt-get install MPC
```

Answer (score -1):

For saving the entire output of dpkg -l to a file:

```
dpkg -l > ~/Desktop/packages
```

and open with a text editor:

```
nano ~/Desktop/packages
```

Comment: what is the point of saving it and editing it, i assume to use the search functionality within nano? If so why not just dpkg -l | grep whatever?

Comment: @drinxy With a limited scrollback buffer size, OP can not read the entire output. Using nano is a solution for that problem. He can also increase scrollback buffer size in preferences of linux terminals, PuTTY etc. But to aviod from eye mistakes, I think nano is a better solution.

Comment: So why not pipe it to less?

Comment: @drinxy I think nano is a more straightforward tool and OP can also use gedit.

Comment: Why not use the tools that are designed for the job? You want to view lots of output use less, need to find a string in output use grep. Both have much more powerful functionality for doing what op is doing and both are as easy to use as nano...